# How to create loader without using Loading controller in ionic-v3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using `ionic-v3` `LoadingController` to show loading but loader is causing the scroll to freeze in latest `iOS` version. Is there a way to create loader without using LoadingController?

Thanks

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Can you please provide me a link? I can not find what is native loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use native loading(spinner)

Install

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-native-spinner
npm install --save @ionic-native/spinner-dialog@4
```

Show loading

```
this.spinnerDialog.show('title', 'message');
this.spinnerDialog.hide();
```

Ref : [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/spinner-dialog/)